# Jackson Serialization Ignore Timezone

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I use the below code for serializing the response that get from an external service an return a json response back as part of my service. However when the external service return a time value along with timezone (10:30:00.000-05.00) , jackson is converting it to 15:30:00. How can I ignore the timezone value?

```
public interface DateFormatMixin {

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getStartTime();
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getEndTime();
}


public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper responseMapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
    responseMapper.addMixIn(Time.class, DateFormatMixin.class);
    return responseMapper;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question but why do you want to ignore the timezone ?

Comment: Hi Gael, I don't want the conversion to happen , hence thought the timezone  could be ignored.

Comment: If you receive both `10:30:00.000-05.00` and `10:30:00.000+02.00` from two separate calls, you want to consider both times as `10:30:00` ? Again.. just trying to understand in which case it could be useful.

Comment: If all times will be with same timezone, I'll consider setting your JVM to this particular timezone.

Comment: Thanks Gael. My assumption was that the application that I consume always returns the same timezone. If I need to ensure the time is not modified ,  should I change the value to HH:mm:ssZ?

Comment: Hi Gael , how can I return time along with timezone returned in the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom deserializer

```
public class CustomJsonTimeDeserializerWithoutTimeZone extends JsonDeserializer<Time>{

    @Override
    public Time deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        Time time = null;
        try{
            Date dt = format.parse("10:30:00.000-05.00".substring(0,12)); // remove incorrect timezone format
            return new Time(dt.getTime());
        }catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

tell jackson to use your custom deserializer

```
public class Model{
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonTimeDeserializerWithoutTimeZone.class)
    private Time time;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonString = ...// jsonString retrieve from external service
Model model = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Model.class);
```

You can use Jackson Custom Serialization to add timezone information for your service response

Comment: Thanks! In my case , I need to serialize as I already have the object with time information.When I serialize , the date gets converted.

Answer (score 1):

You can create deserializer as below:

```
public Calendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    String date = jsonParser.getText();
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(formatter.parse(date));
        return cal;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```